# How to get Mysql Day and Month function equivalents in php

Tags: php

I have a code below which queries mysql record based on day and months and its working fine.

```
    $month = 11;
 $tm = '2020-11-09';
    //pdo.php
    $result = $db->prepare("SELECT tm, DAY(tm) as day from provision where MONTH(tm) = :month");
    $result->execute(array(':month'=>$month));
```

Now I need to get **Mysql Day() and Month()** function equivalents in php.

I have tried code below but its not working. it displays

**Mon** for day instead of **9**  and
**Nov** for month instead of **11**

here is the code

```
$tm = '2020-11-09';
$dt = strtotime($tm);
echo $day = date("D", $dt);

echo "<br><br>";

$mt = strtotime($tm);
echo $month = date("M", $mt);
```

Comment: use `d` and `m` instead. Read the docs: https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change D and M to d and m. you can read this guide https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_date_date.asp

```
<?php
$tm = '2020-11-09';
$dt = strtotime($tm);
echo $day = date("d", $dt);

echo "<br><br>";

$mt = strtotime($tm);
echo $month = date("m", $mt);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use "j" instead of "D" and "m" instead of "M" in first argument of the date() function. Check this for all available formats for the date() function : https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php